# (some) Tests fail when running Postman collection via Newman but pass when running in Postman

Tags: postman, newman

When running my Postman collection, I receive 0 errors throughout the whole suite, but in Newman the tests in two requests fail.

These are my PM tests + relevant body:

```
testsuite = "T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate - "

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test(testsuite + "Status code is 200", function () {pm.response.to.have.status(200);});
pm.test(testsuite + "Succes (true)", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.success).to.eql(true); });
pm.test(testsuite + "No Errors", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.error).to.eql(null); });
pm.test(testsuite + "FishPerHa", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.result.ufsrFishPerHa).to.eql(0)});
pm.test(testsuite + "FeederCountRecommended", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.result.ufsrFeederCountRecommended).to.eql(1)});
pm.test(testsuite + "TimeRangeStart_1", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.result.ufsrTimeRangeResults[0].utrStartTime).to.eql('00:00')});
```

**RELEVANT BODY**
{
"result": {
"ufsrTotalNumberOfFish": 25000,
"ufsrSurvivalPercentage": 100.0,
"ufsrFishPerHa": 0,
"ufsrBiomass": 1.25659535973556,
"ufsrBiomassPercentageFed": 0.0045201895240963965,
"ufsrFeedAmount": 5.68004918110482,
"ufsrFeederCount": 11,
"ufsrFeederCountRecommended": 1,
"ufsrFeederTimeGap": 11,
"ufsrTimeRangeResults": [
{
"utrTimeRangeNr": 1,
"utrStartTime": "00:00",
"utrStopTime": "00:00",

```
testsuite = "T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate by Id - "

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test(testsuite + "Status code is 200", function () {pm.response.to.have.status(200);});
pm.test(testsuite + "Succes (true)", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.success).to.eql(true); });
pm.test(testsuite + "No Errors", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.error).to.eql(null); });
pm.test(testsuite + "FishPerHa", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.result.ufsrFishPerHa).to.eql(0)});
pm.test(testsuite + "FeederCountRecommended", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.result.ufsrFeederCountRecommended).to.eql(1)});
pm.test(testsuite + "TimeRangeStart_1", function() {pm.expect(jsonData.result.ufsrTimeRangeResults[0].utrStartTime).to.eql('00:00')});
```

**RELEVANT BODY**
{
"result": {
"ufsrTotalNumberOfFish": 25000,
"ufsrSurvivalPercentage": 100.0,
"ufsrFishPerHa": 0,
"ufsrBiomass": 1.25659535973556,
"ufsrBiomassPercentageFed": 0.0045201895240963965,
"ufsrFeedAmount": 5.68004918110482,
"ufsrFeederCount": 11,
"ufsrFeederCountRecommended": 1,
"ufsrFeederTimeGap": 11,
"ufsrTimeRangeResults": [
{
"utrTimeRangeNr": 1,
"utrStartTime": "00:00",
"utrStopTime": "00:00",

When running it via Newman, I get the following errors:

```
01.  AssertionError  T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate - Succes (true)                
                      expected false to deeply equal true                                       
                      at assertion:1 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Calculate"                  
                                                                                                
 02.  AssertionError  T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate - No Errors                    
                      expected { Object (code, message, ...) } to deeply equal null             
                      at assertion:2 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Calculate"                  
                                                                                                
 03.  TypeError       T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate - FishPerHa                    
                      Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ufsrFishPerHa')                  
                      at assertion:3 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Calculate"                  
                                                                                                
 04.  TypeError       T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate - FeederCountRecommended       
                      Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ufsrFeederCountRecommended')     
                      at assertion:4 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Calculate"                  
                                                                                                
 05.  TypeError       T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate - TimeRangeStart_1             
                      Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ufsrTimeRangeResults')           
                      at assertion:5 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Calculate"
                                                                                                
 06.  AssertionError  T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate by Id - Succes (true)          
                      expected false to deeply equal true                                       
                      at assertion:1 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Id/Calculate"               
                                                                                                
 07.  AssertionError  T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate by Id - No Errors              
                      expected { Object (code, message, ...) } to deeply equal null             
                      at assertion:2 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Id/Calculate"               
                                                                                                
 08.  TypeError       T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate by Id - FishPerHa              
                      Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ufsrFishPerHa')                  
                      at assertion:3 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Id/Calculate"               
                                                                                                
 09.  TypeError       T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate by Id - FeederCountRecommended 
                      Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ufsrFeederCountRecommended')     
                      at assertion:4 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Id/Calculate"               
                                                                                                
 10.  TypeError       T5 - FeederConfigurator - Unit - Calculate by Id - TimeRangeStart_1       
                      Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ufsrTimeRangeResults')           
                      at assertion:5 in test-script                                             
                      inside "T5 - FeederConfigurator / Unit / Unit/Id/Calculate"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, my initial and current values were not the same in environment variables. PM uses current and Newman uses initial.